# Flash AS3 Looping mc's inside of a function

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have a bunch of movieclips that are animated using TweenLite, (code below), but I would like to loop them 2 or 3 times continuously. I have put them inside of a function but can't seem to get them to loop. The starting positions for each movieclip are defined before this function - an example below also.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong? S

```
private var F_Apricot:Fruit_Apricot;

F_Apricot = new Fruit_Apricot();
        addChild(F_Apricot);    
        F_Apricot.x=222;
        F_Apricot.y=-189;   
        F_Apricot.scaleX=0.7;
        F_Apricot.scaleY=0.7;               
        setChildIndex(F_Apricot, 2);

function fruitLoop():void {             
            TweenLite.to(F_Passion, 1.7, {blurFilter:{blurX:8}, delay:1, x:277, y:325, scaleX:0.7, scaleY:0.7, rotation:28, ease:Cubic.easeOut});
            TweenLite.to(F_Black1, 1.7, {blurFilter:{blurX:8}, delay:1.2, x:238, y:305, scaleX:0.5, scaleY:0.5, rotation:58, ease:Cubic.easeOut});          
            TweenLite.to(F_Apricot, 1.7, {blurFilter:{blurX:8}, delay:1.5, x:303, y:305, scaleX:0.7, scaleY:0.7, rotation:47, ease:Cubic.easeOut});
            TweenLite.to(F_Raspberry, 1.7, {blurFilter:{blurX:8}, delay:1.6, x:207, y:305, scaleX:0.4, scaleY:0.4, rotation:18, ease:Cubic.easeOut});
            TweenLite.to(F_Black2, 1.7, {blurFilter:{blurX:8}, delay:1.7, x:314, y:305, scaleX:0.5, scaleY:0.5, rotation:28, ease:Cubic.easeOut});
            TweenLite.to(F_Cherries, 1.7, {blurFilter:{blurX:8}, delay:2.1, x:288, y:247, scaleX:0.6, scaleY:0.6, rotation:38, ease:Cubic.easeOut});
            TweenLite.to(F_Black3, 1.7, {blurFilter:{blurX:8}, delay:2.3, x:323, y:305, scaleX:0.4, scaleY:0.4, rotation:-8, ease:Cubic.easeOut});          
            TweenLite.to(F_Lime, 1.7, {blurFilter:{blurX:8}, delay:2.4, x:208, y:305, scaleX:0.5, scaleY:0.5, rotation:28, ease:Cubic.easeOut});            
            TweenLite.to(F_Mango, 1.7, {blurFilter:{blurX:8}, delay:2.7, x:205, y:355, scaleX:0.7, scaleY:0.7, rotation:-38, ease:Cubic.easeOut});          
            TweenLite.to(F_Black4, 1.7, {blurFilter:{blurX:8}, delay:2.9, x:188, y:305, scaleX:0.5, scaleY:0.5, rotation:-8, ease:Cubic.easeOut});
            TweenLite.to(F_Raspberry1, 1.7, {blurFilter:{blurX:8}, delay:3, x:303, y:305, scaleX:0.4, scaleY:0.4, rotation:-8, ease:Cubic.easeOut});        
        }       

        fruitLoop();
```

Comment: I see the delays for each fruit are different. Are they meant to loop all in sync, or should each fruit loop independent of the others (i.e. with the shorter delay ones finishing earlier).

Comment: I would check out TimelineLite for this kind of animation. You can append the timeline with each tween and wait for the entire animation to complete and call a function to play the animation again (either forwards or backwards).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TweenLite has a parameter called onComplete which you can use to trigger your next loop.

http://www.greensock.com/as/docs/tween/_tweenlite.html

Answer (score 0):

```
private var F_Apricot:Fruit_Apricot;

F_Apricot = new Fruit_Apricot();
  addChild(F_Apricot);    
  F_Apricot.x=222;
  F_Apricot.y=-189;   
  F_Apricot.scaleX=0.7;
  F_Apricot.scaleY=0.7;               
  setChildIndex(F_Apricot, 2);

function fruitLoop():void {     
  TweenLite.to(F_Passion, 1.7, {blurFilter:{blurX:8}, delay:1, x:277, y:325, scaleX:0.7, scaleY:0.7, rotation:28, ease:Cubic.easeOut});
  TweenLite.to(F_Black1, 1.7, {blurFilter:{blurX:8}, delay:1.2, x:238, y:305, scaleX:0.5, scaleY:0.5, rotation:58, ease:Cubic.easeOut});          
  TweenLite.to(F_Apricot, 1.7, {blurFilter:{blurX:8}, delay:1.5, x:303, y:305, scaleX:0.7, scaleY:0.7, rotation:47, ease:Cubic.easeOut});
  TweenLite.to(F_Raspberry, 1.7, {blurFilter:{blurX:8}, delay:1.6, x:207, y:305, scaleX:0.4, scaleY:0.4, rotation:18, ease:Cubic.easeOut});
  TweenLite.to(F_Black2, 1.7, {blurFilter:{blurX:8}, delay:1.7, x:314, y:305, scaleX:0.5, scaleY:0.5, rotation:28, ease:Cubic.easeOut});
  TweenLite.to(F_Cherries, 1.7, {blurFilter:{blurX:8}, delay:2.1, x:288, y:247, scaleX:0.6, scaleY:0.6, rotation:38, ease:Cubic.easeOut});
  TweenLite.to(F_Black3, 1.7, {blurFilter:{blurX:8}, delay:2.3, x:323, y:305, scaleX:0.4, scaleY:0.4, rotation:-8, ease:Cubic.easeOut});          
  TweenLite.to(F_Lime, 1.7, {blurFilter:{blurX:8}, delay:2.4, x:208, y:305, scaleX:0.5, scaleY:0.5, rotation:28, ease:Cubic.easeOut});            
  TweenLite.to(F_Mango, 1.7, {blurFilter:{blurX:8}, delay:2.7, x:205, y:355, scaleX:0.7, scaleY:0.7, rotation:-38, ease:Cubic.easeOut});          
  TweenLite.to(F_Black4, 1.7, {blurFilter:{blurX:8}, delay:2.9, x:188, y:305, scaleX:0.5, scaleY:0.5, rotation:-8, ease:Cubic.easeOut});
  TweenLite.to(F_Raspberry1, 1.7, {blurFilter:{blurX:8}, delay:3, x:303, y:305, scaleX:0.4, scaleY:0.4, rotation:-8, ease:Cubic.easeOut});  

  if(timer.currentCount>3 ){
    timer.stop()
  }       
}

    var timer:Timer = new Timer( 1000 );
    timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, fruitLoop )
    timer.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the movement to repeat a few times (versus forever) then you can setup all the transitions at once using the "delay" parameter to control what happens when. Make sure to set "overwrite" to false so that all the chained transitions happen, instead of just the last one set.

pseudocode:

```
TweenLite.to(obj, 500, x=0);
TweenLite.to(obj, 500, x=0, delay=500, overwrite=false);
TweenLite.to(obj, 500, x=100, delay=1000, overwrite=false);
TweenLite.to(obj, 500, x=0, delay=1500, overwrite=false);
TweenLite.to(obj, 500, x=100, delay=2000, overwrite=false);
TweenLite.to(obj, 500, x=0, delay=2500, overwrite=false);
```